# Getting handle on DefWindowProc function

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-mobile-6.5

I want a event handler when a window is minimized. I am reading different posts in stackoverflow but not finding a complete solution. My actual issue is [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22051644/application-activate-event-windows-mobile-6-5-compact-edition-application-on-fo)

Similar to what is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8204965/defwindowproc-issue), I want a handle of DefWindowProc in C#. So that I can check if message is WM_ACTIVATEAPP, if the app is activated/de-activated I want to do some business logic.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/410216/2921323) is somwwhat helpful but doesn't explain completely - like how will check the message in my application. Do I need to override `DefWindowProc` ?

Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: This page lists code that allows you to hook the window procedure of controls, maybe you can apply it to a Form too: http://mrpfister.com/programming/subclassing-net-compact-framework-controls/

Answer (score 1):

What about checking for the Form change events:

A simple test form is 'minimized' by the (X) click and re-activated using TaskManager:

```
Load Form:
635291025619140000: Got Form1_Resize()
635291025619950000: Got Form1_Resize()
635291025620060000: Got Form1_Resize()
635291025620300000: Got Form1_Resize()
635291025620470000: Got Form1_Activated()
635291025620880000: Got Form1_GotFocus()

Click on (X) to minimize:
635291026059340000: Got Form1_Resize()
635291026059780000: Got Form1_Deactivate()
635291026059950000: Got Form1_LostFocus()

TaskManager SwitchTo:
635291026483820000: Got Form1_Resize()
635291026483910000: Got Form1_Activated()
635291026484010000: Got Form1_GotFocus()

Press Win-Symbol of Form (shows Start screen):
635291026724060000: Got Form1_Deactivate()
635291026724960000: Got Form1_LostFocus()

Click (X) in Start screen:
635291027163520000: Got Form1_Resize()
635291027163610000: Got Form1_Activated()
635291027163710000: Got Form1_GotFocus()

Click (X) of Form:
635291027673050000: Got Form1_Resize()
635291027673470000: Got Form1_Deactivate()
635291027673660000: Got Form1_LostFocus()

Re-Launched externally:
635291028243720000: Got Form1_Resize()
635291028243900000: Got Form1_Activated()
635291028244010000: Got Form1_GotFocus()
```

You see you always get Deactivated+LostFocus or Activated+GotFocus. You can use Deactivated+LostFocus to catch for the form will be minimized/hidden.
Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Did that test app include controls on the form?  I seemed to recall that a Form will not get focus event unless there are no control on it?

Comment: Right, the form is empty. If not empty, the default or last used element will get the focus message.